# Want to show a popup message while my cursor hovers over a table row. Can anyone yield any outcome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color: coral;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Table</h2>

<p>Move the mouse over the table rows to see the effect.</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to add a popup message when my cursor moves over my row.
I am unable to achieve my goal.
The different rows will yield different popup messages.
I am new with CSS so was unable to solve by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda like this?

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: coral;
}

tr .tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

tr:hover .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Table</h2>

<p>Move the mouse over the table rows to see the effect.</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td class="tooltip">row2</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td>$150</td>
        <td class="tooltip">row2</span>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check out [CSS Tooltips on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)

Comment: If the message pops up instead of table data tag then it would be better.